# Form with submitting url and revealling discountcode

Tags: java, ajax, forms, form-submit

I want to make a custom 404 error page.

Where customers, if they come on this page, have the posibility to send the broken url to us and when they have sended to us they see a discountcode.

So basicly i need a submit button that send the current url of the page, and shows a specific code afterward, but without reloading the page.

Who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you'll need three things to do this:

1)  A custom 404 URL that will point to your 404.html page.  This is configured based on your webserver-specific configuration, so you'll need to make some changes to point to this page.

2)  An Ajax call on your 404 page so that you can make a request without reloading the page.

3)  A server-side code generator that can generate and return a unique one-time-use discount code.

The Ajax is pretty easy to do.  There are a number of different configuration / frameworks online that allow you to make a request without loading the page.  At their core, they usually create a hidden IFrame DOM element with a form inside of it, and submit that form, then close the IFrame.  You'll need to tie into this from the parent frame, having the form that submits get sent back the generated discount code from the server.  You can then access this data from the parent frame, and display it to the user (probably using JavaScript).

One KEY piece of information to this is that your user could just type in some garbage (ex. `http://yourdomainurlhere/oihoaiwhegaweg`) and be redirected to a 404 error, and get a discount code.  Once this knowledge becomes commonplace, people will always do that to get a discount code; thereby invalidating the reasoning you have for wanting to get the broken URL (in order to fix your site).

You can probably try to get around this by checking for referral links, etc., to try to determine if they actually clicked on a link on your site, or if they just arbitrarily typed in a URL.  But this will take much more analysis and possible changes to your entire site to track URL clicking in order to generate the invalid URL.

Comment: Hi Kenzietech, i already tackeled point 1. But i don't know how to write ajax ... could you help me with this?

Comment: I tried to give you a bunch of information already in my answer.  How strong is your HTML / JavaScript skillset?  You can do it using some frameworks such as jQuery, for example, if you don't care to know too much of the detail.  Or if you'd prefer to do it yourself, you can either roll a solution with hidden iFrames that I mentioned above, or you can use XMLHTTPRequests.  Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ for a nice walkthrough on how to do it manually.

Comment: HTML is not my problem ... but beyond that i must say i am weak ...
But i gonna have a look at the w3scools.